# Lista en angular muestra solo [object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar un select con varios titulos. Estoy trabajando con angular y no lo manejo muy a la perfección ya que hace poco que he empezado.Lo que he hecho es dos base de datos una de episodios de star wars y otra de personajes. Un ejemplo seria

> id:2 titulo: Return of the Jedi y el año de estreno.

Y con el personaje tengo su

> id:1, nombre: Luke SkyWalker episodio:2.

El atributo de personaje episodio:2 hace referencia a la id de los episodios. Y en el apartado de personajes quiero hacer un select donde se vean todos los titulos de los episodios disponibles para que cuando el usuario quiera añadir un personaje seleccione este episodio.

En el typescript de personajes hago el import de Episodios y hago el siguiente código:

```
ngOnInit(): void{
    this.ServeApi.obtenerPersonajes().subscribe((personajes: Personaje[]) => {
      this.lPersonajes = personajes;
      this.ServeApi.obtenerEpisodios().subscribe((episodios: Episodio[]) => {
        this.lEpisodio = episodio;
        var j=0;
        var i=0;
        for(i=0;i<this.lPersonajes.length;i++)
        {
          for(j=0;j<this.lEpisodios.length;j++)
          {
              if(this.lEpisodios[j].id == parseInt(this.lPersonajes[i].numEpisodio))
              {
                this.lPersonajes[i].numEpisodio = this.lEpisodio[j].titulo;
              }
          }
          j=0;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Y luego en el html hago esto :

```
<select class="custom-select" name="numEpisodio" [(ngModel)]=personajeSeleccionado.numEpisodio style="max-width: 30%;">
   <option *ngFor="let a of lPersonajes">{{ a }}</option>
</select>
```

Pero en los selects de la web muestra un monton de [object Object] y no se a que deberia ser

Answer (score 1):

En la iteración:

```
<option *ngFor="let a of lPersonajes">{{ a }}</option>
```

La variable `a` es un objeto con varias propiedades así que se debe elegir cual se desea mostrar, por ejemplo: `{{ a.nombre  }}`

Comment: por alguna razón los id y nombre me los muestra. Pero los títulos nop

Comment: Título está en el objeto `a`?